# Handful of IRT scores all exactly the same value

Tags: r, item-response-theory, item-analysis

I am using the mirt package in R to model some latent variables. They seem to be working fine, except that a bunch of the scores generated are exactly the same. Most of the scores are within two or three of zero, and then an handful are 19.999919807.

You can better see it visually. These are the two factors, scored using the ML method from two, 2PL GPCM models:
 [image: graph]

What I'm expecting is a distribution around zero with some infinite values (which were excluded from this visualization). What I'm getting is all of that, plus a whole bunch of factor scores that are exactly the same. Is there anything obvious I'm missing that might cause this?

Thanks.

EDIT: More info I've found that might be relevant while troubleshooting:

- there are (rare) Inf and -Inf results also
- these two models were made from the same data set, but they have no variables in common
- the values going into the IRT model are all lower than 4 (some were negative, but I fixed that-- still getting the weird values)
- there are rare negative scores with the same absolute value (both 19.999919807 and -19.999919807)

Comment: The variables that make up AppScore may cluster at a couple of values.

Comment: They don't seem to.

Comment: ML estimates of $\theta$ are not identified for extreme response patterns (e.g., all correct/incorrect, or all lowest/highest category). Hence, these proxy values are being returned as well. What do the response patterns for these scores look like?